# Canonical location for Django signal receiver functions

Tags: django

Is there a canonical location for implementing Django signal receiver functions? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) suggest models.py, but it seems to me that it would be cleaner if these were organized into a separate own file. (e.g., handlers.py, receivers.py)

Answer (score 1):

It's 2023 now and [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) do not recommend using models.py

> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
> anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
> application’s root module and its models module to minimize
> side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
> submodule of the application they relate to.

Answer (score -1):

The docs recommend models.py because it's a file that is always loaded for each app. You can use whatever file structure you'd like, but no, Django does not look for a particular file for signals. You'll have to import the handlers and connect them in models.py. For example:

#### handlers.py

```
def my_post_save_handler(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something
```

#### models.py

```
from handlers import my_post_save_handler

post_save.connect(my_post_save_handler, sender=MyClass)
```

Comment: The more general condition is for a handler to register a handler for a model that you don't control, i.e. from a reusable app. In that condition, this solution does not work.

Comment: @arustgi: the OP didn't specify such a case, and even then, this is a general guide, and never is it suggested you *have* to do it this way. If you think you have a more enlightened answer, by all means, share. A downvote is completely unwarranted, though.